# How to pin Control Panel to Taskbar using Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I've created this function

```
Function PinToTaskbar($fileLocation, $fileName)
{
    Write-Host "Adding $fileName to taskbar"
    $sa = new-object -c shell.application
    $pn = $sa.namespace($fileLocation).parsename($fileName)  
    $pn.invokeverb('taskbarpin')
}
```

That allows me to pin items to the taskbar such as 
Services

```
PinToTaskbar "$env:windir\System32" 'services.msc'
```

But I am having trouble pinning the Control Panel.
I know I can pin it manually using the search bar so it is possible.
A few things I have tried:

1. `PinToTaskbar "$env:APPDATA\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\System Tools" 'Control Panel'`
2. `PinToTaskbar "$env:APPDATA\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\System Tools" 'Control Panel.lnk'`
3. `$DesktopPath = [Environment]::GetFolderPath("Desktop")
   PinToTaskbar $DesktopPath "Control Panel"`

Comment: Hi, `PinToTaskbar "$env:windir\System32" 'control.exe'` ? Btw, your function does not seem to do anything on my W10 box.

Comment: @sodawillow It is designed for Windows 2012 Server

Comment: There is also a `shell:ControlPanelFolder` command. I have a win2012 instance, I'll do some testing as soon as I can.